# Image resize/crop/flip in .net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, crop, image-resizing, image-rotation

I'm writing an ASP.NET (MVC C#) application where user will have to upload a few images and should be able to **crop** and **rotate** (vertically/horizontally). The application should **resize** the images automatically to fit onto the page.

Do you suggest resizing manually or use something like imageresizing.net (the free licence)? Cons and pros for imageresizing.net ? Any suggestions for tools to crop and rotate as well like jCrop (maybe ones that combine both functionality) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually resizing"? Writing your own routines?

Comment: @Floremin, yes by writing my own code for that.

Comment: http://cropimage.net/ combines ImageResizer and jCrop (albiet with mediocrity), but it might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd always recommend using what's already out there if that fits your needs. You save on development time, but more importantly you save on maintenance and testing. If you're using a library: someone has already tested it and verified, so you can focus on your core. This way, you are "forced" to make your software modular and at a later day you can develop your own library if you need to optimize that part.